# How to make pandas str.contains faster

Tags: python, pandas, search, lambda

How can I make python loop faster through DataFrame columns with 1 million rows and search for a pattern of strings? Should return True or False

`pattern_example = "home|property|house|apartment"`

This is what I have right now

`df[field].str.contains(pattern_example.lower(), case = False, regex=False)`

This is what I am trying to implement

`df[field].apply(lambda x: True if pattern_example.lower() in x else False)`

However, it cannot recognize the OR(|) operator and searchers for full "home|property|house|apartment"

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you need `regex=True`

Comment: if you want to use `|` then you should use `regex=True`

Comment: Also please add a sample of your DataFrame, depending on the patterns of the strings there could be faster ways

Comment: if you want to do this with `apply` and `|` but without `regex` then you would have to split it to list  `["home", "property", "house", "apartment"]` and use `for`-loop (list comprehensive) to check every element from list separatelly `word in x` and finally use `any()` - but this doesn't have to be faster. BTW: probably like this `df[field].apply(lambda text: any(word in text.lower() for word in pattern_example.lower().split('|'))`

Comment: This is something you might need to address in database design or metadata. If what you need to do involves reading 1 million strings and doing something, it's already too late. Maybe regex will improve the constant, but you have a big-O problem.

Answer (score 0):

@furas thanks for the contribution.
It worked.

This is what I used

`df[field].apply(lambda x: True if any (word in x for word in pattern.lower().split('|')) else False)`

Comment: Why are you trying to do this without regex? I suspect it will be faster as `df[field].str.contains(pattern_example.lower(), case = False, regex=True)`